# Change JSON values from iPhone app (possible API needed?)

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I have an app with tutorials. I also have a tab where users can suggest tutorials. Right now, the app loads a table view with an JSON array taken from my website. Every tutorial object in the array looks like this:

> {"string" : "Tutorial Name", "value":1, "devices":
> ["deviceid1","deviceid2"]}

The string is the name of the tutorial they want to see. The value is how many people have voted for it. The devices is an array of strings where I would save the device ID of each user who votes for that tutorial. This is to make sure they do not vote more than once.

Now, what I want the app to do is to change the value key to add one and to add its `deviceID` to the array.

How do I do that in Xcode? I am assuming I might have problems with 2 users trying to change the values at the same time. Should I maybe create a small API for this? Possible create a file that would get the values for me and change them as well?

If so, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Im sorry that I am not a pro. I do my best. Like I said, I am already getting a JSON object and displaying it. I am just worried about users trying to alter the same object at the same time.

I am wondering if I should make the app do this or make a file online manage these values and make my app call that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making changes to the JSON from your app, you are only changing the values locally. This means that the changes won't be updated on the devices of other users who are accessing the app. I think the best way to do this would be to create a small API.

1) You will need to setup a MySQL database that has keys for "string" and "value".

2) Create a PHP script that takes in a string and then adds one to the value field of the database row. This script will be called when a user "votes" for a tutorial.

3) Create a PHP script that queries the data from the database and converts it to JSON format. When loading the app, this script would be called and your app would parse the JSON data and display it into a tableview with the updated values.

Hope this sets you off in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks! You've guided me on the right direction!
Thanks to you I was about to find this great tutorial. 
http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/

I am still figuring out how to change the values but that should take very little research!